# Undefined control sequence \fnwidth

Tags: debugging

I want to do this:

```
\myhref{http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX}{\TeX}
```

but it gives me the error

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> argument \fnwidth
>
> l.10 ...ref{http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX}{TeX}

```
\newcommand{\myhref}[2]{{#2}\protect\footnote{\begin{minipage}{\fnwidth} \ttfamily \url{#1}  \end{minipage}}}
```

Comment: I have no problem with `\href{...}{\TeX}`. The error must be inside of your `\myhref` command.

Comment: Can you please let us know how `\myhref` is defined? I don't know this command.

Comment: `\fnwidth` reminds me on `\footnote` something...

Comment: Don't know. The code is automatically generated from the LaTeX wikibook.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: My compilation complains about `\fnwidth` ... Do you use a package?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  It was my bad.  I added the macro, but still referenced `\href`, not `\myhref`.

Comment: It appears that `\fnwidth` is no generally used length.

Comment: What length should I use?

Comment: `\def\fnwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth-5ex}` perhaps, where the `5ex` approximates the indent of the footnote.

Comment: `\linewidth`...

Comment: that worked! :)

Comment: The whole question is unrelated to the `\TeX` macro, you may want to edit the title.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround unless `\fnwidth` is not defined by some extra package not specified here (the specific value of `\fnwidth` has to be defined at will):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlength{\fnwidth}
\setlength{\fnwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-5ex}
\newcommand{\myhref}[2]{{#2}\protect\footnote{\begin{minipage}[t]{\fnwidth} \ttfamily \url{#1}  \end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}
\myhref{http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX}{\TeX}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, the value of `\fnwidth` should be the text or line width minus the footnote indent.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Should it? ;-)

Comment: Also, the `minipage` needs a `[t]` qualifier.  To see all this, add a very long url.

Comment: It should, lest it go past the right margin.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Well, I will change later on. But I doubt the minipage is necessary at all

Comment: What the minipage accomplishes is to prevent a wrap-around url from resetting all the way to the left margin, and instead remains a left-justified url box.  A matter of taste, but not required.